# Downloading spacy ray in an anaconda virtual environment on linux

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to download spacy ray for spacy v3.0. I want to this within a conda virtual environment where I have spacy v3.0 and other dependencies. I can't figure out how to download it. I tried `conda install spacy-ray` and `conda install -c conda-forge spacy-ray`. These said no such module found. Then I gave up and tried pip install spacy-ray but that gave me the following message:

```
ERROR: Cannot install spacy-ray==0.0.0, spacy-ray==0.1.0 and spacy-ray==0.1.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    spacy-ray 0.1.1 depends on ray<1.0.0 and >=0.8
    spacy-ray 0.1.0 depends on ray<1.0.0 and >=0.8
    spacy-ray 0.0.0 depends on ray<1.0.0 and >=0.8

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

`conda install -c conda-forge spacy[ray]` installed something called openssl. No spacy ray though.

I also tried: (with my environment active):

```
conda install git pip

pip install git+git://github.com/explosion/spacy-ray.git@master
```

To which it said:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray<1.0.0,>=0.8 (from spacy-ray)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ray<1.0.0,>=0.8
```

How would I do this properly?

Comment: You should just be able to do `pip install spacy-ray`

Comment: all of your error messages mention the version number of `ray`, but you never mention which version you have installed

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue with PyPi and the Ray project https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5444 or with the Python 3.7.4 binaries in Anaconda environments  https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11195#issuecomment-521052981

The issue is closed and states that it was fixed but I managed to reproduce your problem using Python 3.7.4

The solution suggests using Python 3.7.3 instead.

`conda create -n ray python=3.7.3`

`pip install -U spacy-ray` should work in the environment with Python 3.7.3.

Comment: So I tried to downgrade the python in my virtual environment by using 'conda install python=3.7.3" followed by 'pip install -U spacy-ray' but this downgraded my spacy to v2.0. Is it possible to use spacy v3.0 with spacy-ray?

Comment: Just for posterity, could you create an environment and then `pip install spacy-ray` before installing anything and let pip pull in whatever dependencies it needs?

Comment: @Word304: `spacy-ray` only works with `spacy>=3.0.0,<3.1.0`, so I'm very surprised that this downgraded spaCy to v2, this shouldn't happen. Any chance you can use just `pip` and not conda? And then follow Shahan's recommendation to just run `pip install spacy-ray`?

Comment: Created a fresh environment and tried again. When I use 'spacy ray train config.cfg ...' it says 'Error: no such command 'ray'. When I try it with 'spacy-ray train config.cfg ...' it says 'spacy-ray: command not found.' However, when I try 'python -m spacy ray --help' it shows me that ray exists and everything seems fine.